# Actions inside Redux Observable epic not being dispatched

Tags: react-native, redux, redux-observable

I cannot get this function to dispatch `UPDATE_REGION` or `GET_CURRENT_POSITION_FULFILLED`

```
...import { Observable } from 'rxjs'
import 'redux-observable'
import { ajax } from 'rxjs/observable/dom/ajax'
import {...
  GET_CURRENT_POSITION,..
} from './action'
import {
  getCurrentPositionFulfilled,
  getCurrentLocationRejected
} from './action'
import type { LocationAction } from './action'
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch'
import { getCurrentPositionObservable } from '../../../../../callbackToObservable'
...

export const getCurrentPositionEpic: Epic<*, *, *> = (
  action$: ActionsObservable<*>
): Observable<LocationAction> =>
  action$.ofType(GET_CURRENT_POSITION).mergeMap(() =>
    getCurrentPosition$
      .mergeMap((position: Position): ActionsObservable<*> => {
        return Observable.of(
          updateRegion({
            region: {
              latitude: position.coords.latitude,
              longitude: position.coords.longitude,
              latitudeDelta: 0,
              longitudeDelta: 0
            }
          }),
          getCurrentPositionFulfilled(position)
        )
      })
      .catch(error => Observable.of(getCurrentLocationRejected(error)))
  )

export const UPDATE_REGION: 'UPDATE_REGION' = 'UPDATE_REGION'    

const getCurrentPosition$ = getCurrentPositionObservable()

type UpdateRegionAction = {
  type: typeof UPDATE_REGION,
  payload: RegionPayload
}

export type MapAction = UpdateRegionAction

export const updateRegion: ActionCreator = (
  payload: RegionPayload
): UpdateRegionAction => ({
  type: UPDATE_REGION,
  payload
})
```

callbackToObservable.js

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs'

export const getCurrentPositionObservable = Observable.bindCallback(
  (options: any, cb?: any) => {
    if (typeof options === 'function') {
      cb = options
      options = null
    }
    navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(cb, null)
  })
```

My only actions that get dispatched:

[image]

index.js

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  product: product
})

export const rootEpic = combineEpics(
  fetchCategoriesEpic,
  getAddPageLocationAutocompleteResultsEpic,
  getAddPageLocationPlaceDetailsEpic,
  getCurrentPositionEpic,
  getCurrentLocationEpic,
  getCurrentLocationFulfilledEpic
)

export const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  vepo,
  composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(createEpicMiddleware(rootEpic)))
)
```

callbackToObservable.js

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs'

export const getCurrentPositionObservable = Observable.bindCallback(
  (options: any, cb?: any) => {
    if (typeof options === 'function') {
      cb = options
      options = null
    }
    navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(cb, null)
  })
```

Why isn't it dispatching `UPDATE_REGION` or `GET_CURRENT_POSITION_FULFILLED`?

Comment: Do I understand correctly that none of your epics is dispatching an action?

Comment: @dentemm fetchCategoriesEpic is an epic in another file and it dispatches an action

Comment: I cannot seem to find anything wrong at first sight, but since you are dispatching two actions simultaneously it might be worth trying to return Observable.concat(updateRegion(...), getCurrentPositionFulfilled(...)) instead of Observable.of(...)

Answer (score 0):

You are dispatching multiple actions simultaneously, so **Observable.concat(Observable.of(), Observable.of())** is the way to go here. Without concat you aren't correctly returning an ActionsObservable.

```
return Observable.concat(
  Observable.of(
    updateRegion({
      region: {
        latitude: position.coords.latitude,
        longitude: position.coords.longitude,
        latitudeDelta: 0,
        longitudeDelta: 0
      }
    }
  ),
  Observable.of(getCurrentPositionFulfilled(position)
)
```